# Empty object check for ASP.NET Core API request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a API controller which receives parameter from body like
`public virtual async Task<ActionResult> TestCommAsync([FromBody] CommRequest commRequest)`

The Comm Request object is as follows

```
 public class CommRequest 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the value that represents the collection of <see cref="CommunicationHistory"/>
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<commItems> commItemsAll{ get; set; }
}
```

When I am passing just `{}` empty object my  condition through postman

`if(commRequest == null)` is not working .. It passes as it is not null.. Need help in proper way checking is null and empty

Comment: `public virtual async` why `virtual` for a API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check whether the property has any item by using `Any()`:

```
if (commItemsAll != null && commItemsAll.Any()) 
{
    return Ok();
}
return BadRequest();
```

or shorter version:

```
if (commItemsAll?.Any() ?? false)
{
    return Ok();
}
return BadRequest();
```

Comment: `Any` might by better that `Count` as it will save having to go through all items in the sequence.

Comment: @Sean you are absolutely right! Thanks for the great advice! I've edited reply!

Answer (score 1):

You should check 'commonItemsAll' for null instead of 'commRequest' . If you send '{}' in body, it means that you send instance (not null) of the model with every property set to null.